# Run Automator App conditionally at system startup

Tags: automator

i have build an Automator app working every time at system startup. 
But sometime i wish to do not run it. There is a way to avoid (like holding a key at boot for example) Automator App runs when it do not need?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternate method:

You can include the Automator app on Startup (System Preferences => Users and Groups => Login Items => Click `+` and browse to `Automator.app` in `Finder`.
You can see an example here.
[image]

This will have it working every time on startup.

### Turning it off (temporarily)

If you hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down just as your computer starts to log you into OS X (not when you hear the chime), it will ignore all of your login items. I could only get this working with automatic login disabled. You have to hit it right as your computer starts to log you in.

This may not be convenient if you have more `Login Items` in your `Users & Groups`, but it is a good place to start.

### References

http://lifehacker.com/5795904/temporarily-disable-your-macs-login-items-with-the-shift-key

Comment: Thanks @sameetandpotatoes, good tricks! My App was still in login items, but i did not remember "safe mode" boot. This sure solve my issue when i do not want start my App. Doing it start on boot i think there is not other way to do it.

Comment: Glad you found it useful, Eddie. Be sure to accept my answer too if this solves your issue.